# Why can't express send using this promise syntax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

Normally when using Promise syntax, the below syntaxes produce the same result:

```js
// Syntax A - works fine
getUser(id).then((user) => console.log(user)

// Syntax B - works fine
getUser(id).then(console.log)
```

Yet when we attempt this in an Express route, only syntax A works:

```js
// Works
app.get('/syntax_a', (req, res) => {
  getUser(req.body.id).then((user) => res.json(user))
})

// Fails
app.get('/syntax_b', (req, res) => {
  getUser(req.body.id).then(res.json)
})
```

Syntax B yields an error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined
    at json (/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:256:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Why isn't this working like the first example?

Comment: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: When you pass a method of an object (like `res.json`), you break the relationship between the method (the `json()` method) and the object (`res`).  That means that inside that method, `this` won't work properly.

Comment: In addition to the comments above, following change will fix the issue: `res.json` ---> `res.json.bind(res)`

Comment: And why does it work with console? Because internally `console.log` has no dependency on `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because `response.json` is a function [that looks up `app` on `this`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/06d11755c99fe4c1cddf8b889a687448b568472d/lib/response.js#L239-L256).  When you pass `res.json` you're passing `json` without any reference to the object it comes from so its `this` is (most likely) `undefined`).  `this` in JavaScript is *dynamically* bound, rather than statically bound as it is in a language like C# or Java.

`console.log` on the other hand doesn't use `this` and so isn't affected by how you call it.

We can build something like this ourselves:

```js
let _privateImplementation = (...args) => console.log(...args);

let ourPrivateBoundExample = {
  doIt(some, info) {
    _privateImplementation("Doing it", some, info);
  }
}

ourPrivateBoundExample.doIt(1, 2); // Doing it 1 2
Promise.resolve("Hello there!")
  .then(ourPrivateBoundExample.doIt) // Doing it Hello there!
```